# Gauss law example - Electric field and dA

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

I am still very confused and lost. I still dont understand why E1 is pointing down , E3 and 2 pointing up. while dA is point the left and dA2 and dA3 are in the same direction of the E3 and E2.

I still cant figure out :(

Could anyone show a diagram or something to illustrate the direction of electric field and dA?

Comment: Hi KL DC. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Electric fields point **away from** positive charge and **towards** negative charges.
  Don't think about the cylinder drawn. The only think that matters for the field direction is the charge in the wire.

Think of it like this: The electric field at *any point* points in the direction a positive charge would move. That means, a positive charge would move *away* from another positive charge (therefore the field arrows in the drawing you have point *away* from the positive charged wire in your figure.)

- The $dA$ parts are simply **small areas**. If I were to talk about a small area of the cylinder surface, then I would also like to know which side is inwards and which side is outwards in the cylinder in the figure. Therefore the areas are given *a direction* at the same time. This is called a *normal* to the area.
  Then if you couldn't see the cylinder, but I told you that I have an area $d \vec A_1$ that points to the left, you would know that the cylinder is on the right hand side of this portion of the surface area. It is simply a matter of definition.

Area $d \vec A_1$ points left because it is on the **left** end of the cylinder (so it points *outwards* from the cylinder).
Area $d \vec A_2$ points right because it is on the **right** end of the cylinder.
Area $d \vec A_3$ is placed at the curved cylinder surface. It therefore points *out from the surface* away from the cylinder.

> dA2 and dA3 are in the same direction of the E3 and E2.

$d\vec A_2$ and $E_2$ are not in the same direction on the drawing. I don't know what you mean here.

$d\vec A_3$ and $E_3$ *are indeed* in the same direction on the drawing. This is simply because, the $d\vec A_3$ will point straight out of the curved cylinder surface (perpendicular to the surface) at any point on the curved surface - and $E_3$ happens to do exactly the same, since it always points *away* from the wire in the center of the cylinder. So at any point on that curved surface, those two point in the same direction.